# Google Cloud Messaging - GCM - SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, service-not-available

I am trying, to implement the new GCM, I am following Google *get stated* :
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

I getting stuck at getting my device registration ID !

My app keep trying to connect with Google server, Here my error logs :

```
onReceive: com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY
GCM IntentService class: com.dombox.app.GCMIntentService
Acquiring wakelock
[GCMIntentService] start
Registering app com.dombox.app of senders _my_sender_id_
Releasing wakelock
onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
GCM IntentService class: com.dombox.app.GCMIntentService
Acquiring wakelock
[GCMIntentService] start
handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered = null
Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
Scheduling registration retry, backoff = 912617 (768000)
Releasing wakelock
```

Here is my Activity Code, asking for an ID :

```
    try{
        Log.i(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] checkDevice");
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        Log.i(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] checkManifest");
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] reg id : "+GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
        }
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // SENDER_ID is my project id into google account url
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
            Log.i(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] reg id : "+GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] already registered as : " + regId);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] Exception : "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here my Service code

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
           // SENDER_ID is my project id into google account url
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Log.d(TAG, "[GCMIntentService] start");
}


public GCMIntentService(String senderId) {
    super(senderId);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Log.d(TAG, "[GCMIntentService] start - sender Id : "+senderId);
}
}
```

And here is my Android Manifest :

```
<permission android:name="com.dombox.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.dombox.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.myapp.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" android:enabled="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Myapp"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

I'm following Google's instruction, but I stuck with this SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error,

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem was not code related, but link to the test phone.
**The test phone do not have a SIM, and the clock was not set**. So google cannot resgistred it with a wrong time.

I manage to have a registration Id using a Android Virtual Device, with google api, and by **setting the test phone clock**.

Comment: I had the same problem with known working code and it was due to the time being set incorrectly

Comment: Did you experience this scenario?
The app used to run smoothly in my virtual(google api), but now it is stuck at the service_not_available - retry cycle.

Comment: what was the version of android on your avd??

Comment: I am using samsung S2 mobile, bug getting service_not_available alwasys. Please help.

Comment: @Tommecpe could you set this as the accepted answer? Since this IS the one that helped you, and me aswell.

Comment: alright, done. A bit old but I'm sure it can since help people

Comment: The time was correct on my Android 5.0.2 device, however it did not have a SIM. Worked fine on an identical device with a SIM in it.

Answer (score 7):

```
android:enabled="true"
```

Remove this ^

If you don't already add this to your manifest

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="8"
```

You don't need the second constructor in GCMIntentService. only this one

```
public GCMIntentService() {         
 super(SENDER_ID);  }
```

Ensure that your SENDER_ID is the number copied out of the URL from your browser while you are browsing the google code website AND browsing the GCM service.

Comment: be careful with the targetSdkVersion I posted. It may affect you layouts and throw possible exceptions when you run on a new SDK

Comment: I set my `target API level` to 8 and my `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>`. But I am still stuck with a SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error

Comment: @Tommecpe just resolved the SERVICE_NOT_AVALIBLE Issue. check in your catalog if you get a RegID, if not reboot your device and try again this resolved it for me.

Comment: your XML tag    <minSdkVersion="3"/> must be <minSdkVersion="8"/> I'm confused by your round-about comment

Comment: The problem was not code related, but link to the google account use in the test phone, or the test phone it self.

I manage to have a registration Id using a Android Virtual Device, with google api. Thank you for you help

Comment: device factory reset helped me

Answer (score 3):

Remember that if you're behind a corporate firewall, some ports that GCM uses may not be allowed to communicate over the local wireless. I had this problem when trying to get my emulator to work initially. I had to get a special IP that allowed the ports listed below through.

---

> Note: If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic
>   to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow
>   connectivity with GCM in order for your Android devices to receive
>   messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically
>   only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't
>   provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept
>   outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks
>   listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem...my solution was to disable internet connection and use the phone service.

Comment: Using 3G of the tablet instead of the Wifi connection worked for me, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem and it was caused by the WIFI connection. I turned WIFI off and made the test again (on 3g) and it Worked. Then I turned the WIFI back on and had the error again. Back to 3g, to make sure, and it worked again.

So, in conclusion, the issue was caused by the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem running my application on genymotion. Installing google play services like it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt?answertab=active#tab-top) and everything worked fine.